# Boolean masks for vectors (or iterators)

Tags: rust

What's the most efficient way to implement boolean masking with vectors in Rust?

There might be a crate that does this(?), but to help me learn, I'd also like to hear about:

- how you'd do this without a crate (i.e. have I missed something in the standard library?), and;
- whether bool masking can be extended to lists and iterators more generally.

My example below applies the bool vector [true, false, false, true] to mask out the true indices of a u32 vector [1, 2, 3, 4]. This returns [2, 3].

I'm using a clunky for loop; can we do it better using e.g. maps and iterators?

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mask = vec![true, false, false, true];

    remove_true(&mut numbers, &mask); // remove numbers where vector mask == true
    println!("{:?}", numbers)
}

// Using a for loop
fn remove_true(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, locs: &Vec<bool>) {
    for m in (0..locs.len()).rev() {
        // Loop in reverse to preserve indices when dropping values
        if locs[m] == true {
            vec.remove(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) can be used for this operation, in fact this sort of selection is one of the example snippets:

```rust
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let keep = [false, true, true, false, true];
let mut iter = keep.iter();
vec.retain(|_| *iter.next().unwrap());
assert_eq!(vec, [2, 3, 5]);
```

Since you're performing a negative selection (excluding the selected items) you have to reverse the result, but that aside it's identical (in fact it's a tad simpler because `!` doesn't require dereferencing):

```rust
fn remove_true(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, locs: &[bool]) {
    let mut drop = locs.into_iter();
    vec.retain(|_| !drop.next().unwrap())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant. No doubt will speed up performance over the for loop when sieving much larger vectors.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does dereferencing do here for `*iter.next()`?

Comment: [You can put the code in the playground and alter it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57e22c579c5c1298ac8ff8e80910ee02) and it'll tell you: `iter` is a `std::slice::Iter`, and `Iter::Item = &T`, so `iter.next()` hands out `Option<&bool>`. Since `retain` requires a `bool`, the dereference forces a `Copy`.

Answer (score 2):

A masking can be abstracted as a `zip`+`filter` over iterators too:

```rust
fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mask = vec![true, false, false, true];

    let filtered: Vec<_> = numbers
        .iter()
        .zip(mask.iter())
        .filter_map(|(v, c)| if c { Some(v) } else { None })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", numbers)
}
```

Comment: You end up with a `Vec<(int, bool)>` so you need one more step of mapping, or to use `filter_map`. And of course it doesn't work in-place, which I assumed was the OP's specific desire.

Comment: @Masklinn, indeed, you are right, let me fix it. I'm not so sure he wanted to do it inplace tough, since he also asked about masking iterators, that is why my answer (to complement yours :) )

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the iterator example -- means that I have an idea of how to mask anything that can be iterated.